# Why doesn't getActivity() on a listfragment work when ran from a dialogfragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

My ListFragment is in a viewpager and the actionbar has a button that opens a dialogfragment. Then I'm trying to call a function with non-static methods to update my simple adapter from that dialogfragment like this:

**MyDialogFragment.java**

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle(R.string.dialogtitle);
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.items, indx, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

MyListFragment updateItems = new MyListFragment();      

               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   updateItems.updater();
                   dialog.dismiss();
                   ...
}
}
```

**MyListFragment.java**

```
public void updater(){
      ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = buildData();

String[] from = { "name", "address", "postalcode", "item", "item2", "item3" };
int[] to = { R.id.title, R.id.address, R.id.postalcode, R.id.item1, R.id.imageView1, R.id.item3 };

ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), list,
    R.layout.rowlayout, from, to);
setListAdapter(adapter);    
}
```

`ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), list, R.layout.rowlayout, from, to)` line gives me null pointer exception.

Fragment should be attached since I tried the lifecycle of that fragment by adding `System.out.println("onAttach")` (or onResume and etc.) to every step to make sure that the status of the fragment isn't changed when the dialog box is opened.

I also added a button to that listfragment to do `"updater();"` and it works as supposed to.

Any good ideas why this doesn't work when run from a different fragment?

Thank you for your help!

**EDIT**

Managed to get rid of the null pointer exception by adding
    `Context context;` to the start of the ListFragment and `context = getActivity();` to the onCreate method and using that context instead of getActivity on the updater function. I added a couple of System.out.printlns to that function which are printed out just fine, but the listview itself still isn't updated. Can't understand why because the fragment as I know seems to be active (or attached) and the function works fine when ran from the fragment itself.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the arraylist initialization is not done properly ..

Hope you try this ...

if any mistake occurs post your build data method .It will be fixed .

```
  ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
  list = buildData();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That could have caused some other problems if it wasn't fixed. I tested this by adding
`Context context = getActivity();
 System.out.println(context);
 System.out.println(list)` and context shows null. The list prints out ok.